# Found a hidden port . . . what now?

Tags: security, rkhunter

I ran rkhunter and found an open hidden port. How do I close a port that is not listed with the netstat or fuser command? It is hidden from these which is why it was flagged. Aside from blocking the port with ufw or iptables, how can I remove or close this port?

```
Starting TCP checking

Found Hidden port that not appears in netstat: 38598
Starting UDP checking
```

Comment: which port number is open? can you add the output of rkhunter.

Comment: Shown is the output of unhide-tcp which I believe is the command called by rkhunter, the output is the same anyhow.

Comment: You could try `lsof -Pan -i tcp -i udp` [source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/702/lists-all-listening-ports-together-with-the-pid-of-the-associated-process)

Comment: I do like that lsof command but it doesn't show up in the output and it still shows up for unhide.

Comment: Does `nmap` show that port open for your machine? (with `nmap -p 38598 YOUR_MACHINE_IP`)

Comment: Also, what is the output of `cat /proc/net/sockstat | grep TCP`

Answer (score 1):

To simply close the port `38598` you can use UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall)

UFW is used by default by Ubuntu as it's firewall and is easy to customize and has a easy to use syntax.

Just type the following in the terminal.

1. Check the status of UFW.

`sudo ufw status`

If it's inactive then enable it using the command

`sudo ufw enable`

2.Close the port

to close a particular port number use

`sudo ufw deny port-number`

where port-number is the port number you want to disable access to.

To re enable closed port use:

`sudo ufw allow port-number`

for more info see [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Comment: +1 UFW is Uncomplicated firewall? Or Ubuntu firewall? I always thought it as Ubuntu firewall.

Comment: Thanks, ufw seems to do the job of blocking it but I'd still like to remove whatever it is completely.